# PowerBuilder and batch processing

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, powerbuilder

I'm using PowerBuilder 10.5 and as a newbie I'm a bit stuck and since Google isn't giving me a satisfying answer I'm asking some advice from the Stack Overflow group. 
I have a Rich Text Edit field in which the user can write something, insert pictures and so forth. Once finished, he goes to the „Search“ command button and clicking it searches for the batch file that will suit his needs (copy that text into an existing word document, create a new word and place the folder on web, and so fort – there are 6 different batches). The code in the clicked event of „Search“ command button is this:

```
String ls_s
GetFileOpenName('PB_app', ls_s, ls_s, 'BAT', "Win Batch Files (*.BAT),*.BAT", 'C:\Programs\Test')
```

And here come my problems: I can't connect my app and the selected batch file. I'd like the path of the selected batch file to be visible in the Single Line Edit filed, but I have no idea how to get there, not to mention I'm point blank at how to connect PB app, batch file, how to even say to the batch file – „That text in rich text edit field is the one you have to work with?“…?
So I need some advice, guidance, perhaps some links or names of any literature that would help me understand how it should be done.  I've lost two days and got nowhere, and I just need some piece of advice to get me going…

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the original programmer used one variable for two return values. If you declare a new string variable and pass it instead of the first ls_s, you'll see this will return you the path. If you run into trouble, PB has a good help file (and the manuals are also online) which covers GetFileOpenName().

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: Terry... Thanks for the advice, but after some googling I've decided to go with OLE objects to solve this matter. It somewhat seems as a simpler solution?!

Comment: Windows Scripting Host seems to be the most foolproof way to run a program from PB. To get the path for the batch file I'd do it Terry's way.